# Why is $L(x) = x^{o(1)}$ for any slowly varying function $L$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, slowly-varying-functions

**Question**

I've heard that for any slowly varying function $L$, it's true that $L(x) = x^{o(1)}$. But why is this the case?

*Note:* Here I'm using the standard (Karamata) definition of [slow variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function#:%7E:text=Definition%201.%20A%20measurable%20function%20L%C2%A0%3A%C2%A0(0%2C%20%2B%E2%88%9E)%C2%A0%E2%86%92%C2%A0(0%2C%20%2B%E2%88%9E)%20is%20called%20slowly%20varying%20(at%20infinity)%20if%20for%20all%20a%20%3E%200%2C), namely a measurable function $L : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is called *slowly varying* if
$$
\frac{L(\gamma x)}{L(x)} \underset{x \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1 \quad \text{for all $\gamma > 0$.}
$$

**Thoughts/Attempt**

From the [Karamata representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function#Karamata_representation_theorem) of $L$, we have
$$
L(x) = \exp\left\{ \eta(x) + \int_B^x \frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t} dt \right\}, \quad \text{for all $x > B$,}
$$
for some $B>0$ and some bounded measurable functions $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ with $\lim_{x \to \infty} \varepsilon(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \eta(x) \in \mathbb R$.

So,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&& L(x) &= x^{o(1)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow & \log L(x) &= \eta(x) + \int_B^x \frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t} dt = o(1) \cdot \log x \\
 &\Leftrightarrow & \underbrace{\frac{\eta(x)}{\log x} }_{\to 0} + \frac{1}{\log x} \int_B^x \frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t} dt &= o(1) \\
&\Leftrightarrow & \frac{1}{\log x} \int_{\log B}^{\log x} \varepsilon\big(\text e^u \big) du &= o(1) \qquad \text{($u := \log t$)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The term on the left-hand side of the last line is clearly $O(1)$. But why is it $o(1)$ -- i.e. why does it have to converge to $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\de\delta$Take any real $\de>0$. Since $\ep(t)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$, there is some real $t_\de>B$ such that $|\ep(t)|\le\de$ for all $t\ge t_\de$. So, for $x>\max(1,t_\de)$,
$$\Big|\int_{t_\de}^x\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt\Big|
\le\de\,\int_{t_\de}^x\frac1t\,dt=\de(\ln x-\ln t_\de)$$
and hence
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}\Big|\int_{t_\de}^x\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt\Big|
\le\de\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x-\ln t_\de}{\ln x}=\de.$$
So,
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}\Big|\int_B^x\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt\Big| \\ 
\le\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}\Big|\int_B^{t_\de}\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt\Big|
+\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}\Big|\int_{t_\de}^x\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt\Big| \\ 
\le0+\de=\de,$$
for any real $\de>0$. So,
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}\Big|\int_B^x\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt\Big|=0,$$
that is,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\ln x}\int_B^x\frac{\ep(t)}t\,dt=0,$$
as desired.